# Blazor detect change on select element inside a foreach loop

Tags: c#, html, razor, blazor

I have a root object with a property named Exercises, which is a List. In my HTML I loop over this list as below:

```
@foreach(WorkoutExerciseDto workoutExerciseDto in Workout.Exercises){
    <select class="form-select" @bind="workoutExerciseDto.ExerciseId">
        <option value="1">Exercise 1</option>
        <option value="2">Exercise 2</option>
        <option value="3">Exercise 3</option>
    </select>
}
```

In my code section I have this method:

```cs
public void GetChangedObject(WorkoutExerciseDto workoutExerciseDto){
    // When a value has been selected I want the WorkoutExerciseDto object in that foreach loop. 
}
```

So, when a new value has been selected I want that changed object in the GetChangedObject method. How do I do this? I can't set the onchange attribute because I already used the bind attribute. I could wing this, but I would like to know the best method to approach my problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@onchange` directive alongside another directive like `@oninput`, just need to specify that the first `@bind` is for the `oninput` event.

```
@foreach(WorkoutExerciseDto workoutExerciseDto in Workout.Exercises){
    <select class="form-select" 
    @bind="workoutExerciseDto.ExerciseId" @bind:event="oninput"
    @onchange="() => GetChangedObject(workoutExerciseDto)">
        <option value="1">Exercise 1</option>
        <option value="2">Exercise 2</option>
        <option value="3">Exercise 3</option>
    </select>
}
```

[Snippet demo](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/cHPOGdFx16Us15Su38)